# Autokey: Capslock and a character will not map to Left

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use Capslock to modify hjkl to arrows to simulate vim but I keep getting an error.

```
Capslock & h::Left
```

I get an error:

```
Line Text: Left
Error: This line does not contain a recognised action
```

Capslock is later remapped to Esc.

If I use the mapping to fire off a new window it works without fault.

Is there a way to achieve this?

My keyboard doesn't have a left windows key so I cannot use the windows key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Capslock & h::send, {left}
```

It works for me this way.